# Insert line between lines in linux where the line contains special chars

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file, which I need to add a line between these lines :

```
[%- IF ssl.defined %]
ssl = [% ssl %]
[%- ELSE %]
```

.. which should result in the following

```
[%- IF ssl.defined %]
ssl = [% ssl %]
ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
[%- ELSE %]
```

How can I do this ?

*ideally in a manner that can be run from within a bash script*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width sed :

```
sed '/\[%- ELSE %\]/i ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048' file
```

Inserts the line before the `[% -ELSE %]` line.

To insert between `ssl = [% ssl %]` and `[% -ELSE %]` :

```
sed '/ssl = \[% ssl %\]/,/\[%- ELSE %\]/ { 
  /\[%- ELSE %\]/i ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
}' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed with option `-i`.

```
sed -i '/ssl = \[% ssl %\]/,/\[%- ELSE %\]/ { 
  /\[%- ELSE %\]/i ssl_dh_parameters_length = 2048
}' file
```

Comment: This would work, except there are multiple else statements in the file both before and after this segment.

Comment: `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched \`{'`

Comment: That is so bizzare.  It worked on multi-line but not as a single line :)   Thank you !

Comment: It's because the one-line includes the closing `}` in the string to insert.